# How do I configure page properties in AEM 6?

Tags: aem

I need to add some page metadata (SEO, Open Graph, etc) and have it be editable per page. In CQ5 I modified the page component dialog.xml to allow for custom fields and it was accessible through the sidekick. In the AEM 6 Touch UI, the sidekick is gone and the page properties available under the gear is configured in some other way that seemingly isn't documented. Is there a way to configure this in AEM 6? Or some other way to edit metadata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Touch UI uses different node type for its dialogs (cq:dialog vs dialog), check this article for details: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-component.html

Comment: I spent a ton of time searching and came up with nothing. I can't find any mention in the main product documentation. It seems that regular components will use either dialog of cq:dialog, but page properties use one or the other depending on which UI.

Comment: You are right, Touch UI documentation is far from perfect, you'll have to google a lot in order to find your answers

Answer (score 2):

In AEM 6.1 you can use the sling resource merger to override/extend/hide existing touch ui dialogs nodes/properties as described here:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/platform/sling-resource-merger.html

Let's say for example you would like to add a new textfield (SEO) to the basic tab during page creation.

Then you need to do the following:

1. create the following node structure:
   /apps/foundation/components/page/cq:dialog/content/items/tabs/items/basic/items/column/items/title/items/seo, just the node structure without any content. All nodes can be of nt:unstructured.
2. Set the property "sling:resourceSuperType" with the value "/libs/foundation/components/page/cq:dialog" on the node "/apps/foundation/components/page/cq:dialog"
3. Assign the following properties to the "seo" node you created

```
sling:resourceType:granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield
fieldLabel:SEO
cq:showOnCreate:{Boolean}true
cq:hideOnEdit:{Boolean}false
name:./seo
```

When you create a new page in the touch UI mode then the new textfield SEO should display in the basic tab.